# DetailViewController doesn't receive the Array of objects?

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform, segue

I have no errors in my code, but the array on the detail Viewcontroller isn't receiving the objects I'm sending to it via the segue.I know my array is full of objects because I can print them to the logs.I can count them before the prepare for segue, then after the segue, the array is empty on the detailVC. hopefully you can help!

```
var route:[PFObject] = [PFObject]()


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {


  if segue == "toRoutesDetailVC" {


if let indexPath = self.tableView?.indexPathForSelectedRow()?.row {

let nav = segue.destinationViewController as! PoolRouteDetailVC

  var objects = self.route[indexPath] as! PFObject


nav.currentObjects = [objects]
```

---

Detail VC

```
var currentObjects:[PFObject] = [PFObject]()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace

`if segue == "toRoutesDetailVC"`

with

`if segue.identifier == "toRoutesDetailVC"`

and it will work fine.